# Atualizar ListView

Tags: android, listview

Quando eu clico em minha ListView, eu abro um diálogo com 3 botões(Editar, Excluir e Voltar).
Ao clicar em excluir, gostaria de fazer com que a ListView fosse atualizada.
Em que momento eu devo fazer isso?

```
public class Relacao_cliente extends Activity {

private static final Comum c1 = new Comum();
private final ListView ListViewR_Cliente = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRelacao_Cliente);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_relacao_cliente);

    Populate_ListView();


}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) ListViewR_Cliente.getAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void Populate_ListView()
{

    try {
        ClienteDAO BD = new ClienteDAO(this);
        //LISTA DE CLIENTES GERADA PELO MÉTODO LISTAR_CLIENTES()
        ArrayList<Cliente> Lista_Clientes =  BD.Listar_Clientes();

        if(!Lista_Clientes.isEmpty())
        {
            //SE A LISTA NÃO ESTIVER VAZIA, ENTÃO EU SETO MEU ADAPTER.
            ListViewR_Cliente.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(this, Lista_Clientes,ListViewR_Cliente));

        }else{

            //c1.Exibir_Mensagem(this, "Não existe nenhum cliente cadastrado!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        c1.Exibir_Mensagem(this, e.getMessage().toString());
    }
}


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
static TabHost tabHost;

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Cliente> list;
private ListView MyListView;


public ClienteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cliente> list, ListView lv){
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.MyListView = lv;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    //list.get(position);
    return  list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Cliente cCliente = list.get(position);
    View layout;
    final Comum c1 = new Comum();

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itens_relacao_cliente, null);
    }else
    {
        layout = convertView;
    }


    //Campos da minha list view pré definida.
    TextView Nome = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lblNome);
    Nome.setText(cCliente.getNome());

    TextView Apelido = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lblApelido);
    Apelido.setText("Apelido: " + cCliente.getApelido());

    //MyListView.setClickable(true);
    MyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Cliente C = (Cliente) list.get(position);

         Dialog_Info_Cli d1 = new Dialog_Info_Cli();
         d1.Exibir_Info_Cliente(context, C);

    }
    }); 

    return layout;
}




}
```

Dialogo:

```
public class Dialog_Info_Cli {
private AlertDialog alerta;
final Comum c1 = new Comum();

public void Exibir_Info_Cliente(final Context context, String Titulo,final Cliente C) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_info_cli, null); 

    TextView Nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblNome);
    Nome.setText(C.getNome());

    TextView Fone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTelefone);
    Fone.setText("Fone: (" + C.getDDD() + ")" + C.getCelular() );

    TextView Apelido = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblApelido);
    Apelido.setText("Apelido: (" + C.getApelido()+ ")");

    TextView Obs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblValor_Obs);
    Obs.setText("" + C.getObservacao());


     view.findViewById(R.id.btnEditar).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cadastro_cliente.class);
            intent.putExtra("Cliente", C);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            alerta.dismiss(); 
        } 
    }); 


    view.findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
             alert.setMessage("Deseja excluir o cliente?");

            alert.setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                ClienteDAO db = new ClienteDAO(context);
                try {
                    db.Deletar_Cliente(C);
                    c1.Exibir_Mensagem(context, "Registro Excluido com sucesso!");
                    alerta.dismiss(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    c1.Exibir_Mensagem(context, "Erro ao excluir cliente!");
                }


              }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("NÃO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
              }
            });

            alert.show();

         } });


        view.findViewById(R.id.btnHome).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                alerta.dismiss(); 
            } 
        }); 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
        builder.setTitle("Informações do Cliente"); 
        builder.setView(view); 
        alerta = builder.create(); 
        alerta.show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Se for apagado com sucesso atualizas a `ListView`.

Comment: Coloca o código de excluir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logo depois de excluir os dados do storage local, vc atualiza sua view, mas pra isso vc deve ter certeza que os dados foram excluídos do storage. Para atualizar sua view vc pode fazer de algumas formas, vou te mostrar as mais simples.

1. Você pode repopular seu `ListView` na activity, chamando novamente `Populate_ListView()`. Funciona, porém não é o melhor método pois vc desperdiçará processamento recarregando toda sua lista. Se for uma lista grande de items complexos isso pode tornar a app lenta.
2. Você pode excluir seu item direto da sua `ListView`, utilizando os seguintes métodos:

   ```
   listView.removeViewAt(adapter.getPosition(C)); // C o seu objeto do tipo Cliente
   ```

ou:

```
    listView.removeView(child); // child é um objeto do tipo View criado pelo seu adapter
```

ou:

```
    adapter.remove(C); // C o seu objeto do tipo Cliente
    // utilizar ListView.setAdapter(adapter); para recarregar o adapter caso seja necessario
```

Creio que a primeira opção resolverá seu problema. Como o dialogo está em classe diferente, vc pode utilizar uma interface para fazer o callback e excluir seu item da ListView.